# Объясните пожалуйста код

Tags: c++

Я немного не понимаю данный код, а точнее кусок кода, связанный с массивом и циклом for.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char find[3][3] = { {'0', '0', '0'}, {'0', '0', '0'}, {'0', '0', '0'} };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            cout << find[i][x];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И какая строчка вызывает затруднение?

Comment: char find[3][3] = { {'0', '0', '0'}, {'0', '0', '0'}, {'0', '0', '0'} };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            cout << find[i][x];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

Comment: И какое *конкретное* выражение в этих строках вызывает затруднение?

Comment: Это вывод. Почему он таковым получается.

Comment: Ну тогда приводите фактический вывод и ожидаемый вывод и расскажите почему вы ожидаете именно такой вывод.

Comment: Приложите тогда к вопросу текстовку вашего описания, ход мыслей - а то в текущем виде мы знаем лишь то, что вам тут что-то непонятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый цикл `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` отвечает за индекс строки.
То есть им мы получаем, из какой строки мы будем брать значения из столбцов.

Второй цикл `for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)` отвечает за индекс столбца.
То есть им мы получаем, какой нам столбец выбрать в строке.

`cout << find[i][x];` - выводим элемент массива из `i-ой` строчки и `x-го` столбца.

`cout << endl;` - после вывода строки переходим на следующую строчку. Если этой строки не будет, то программа так и продолжит выводить значения в одну строку.

Получится:

```
000000000
```

Вместо:

```
000
000
000
```

Также стоило бы добавить `<<'\t'` к `cout << find[i][x];`, чтобы значения не слипались.
Н-р, `131` можно интерпретировать как `131`, `13` и `1`, `1` и `13`, `1` и `3` и `1`

Comment: Большое спасибо! А то я на этой теме немного застрял.

Answer (score 1):

Эх, Вас сейчас за минусят...
Вы хоть учебник открывали? Можете не отвечать - и так видно
Вот - см. комментарии

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Объявляем двумерный массив символов 3 на 3. И загоняем в него 3 одномерных массива-строки (000, 000 и 000)
    char find[3][3] = { {'0', '0', '0'}, {'0', '0', '0'}, {'0', '0', '0'} };
    //Здесь проход сверху в низ
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        // Здесь проход с лева направо
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
        // Здесь выводим символ из ячейки массива
        cout << find[i][x];
        // Я бы добавил сюда разделитель, чтоб не 000, а, например, 0|0|0|
        }
    // Переход на новую строку
    cout << endl;
    }
    // Говорим всем, что программа выполнена без ошибок
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char find[3][3] = { {'0', '0', '0'}, {'0', '0', '0'}, {'0', '0', '0'} };
```

Мы создаем массив состоящий из 3 строк, в каждой из этих строк будет еще 3 значения

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

Цикл отвечает за номер строки массива find

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
```

Этот цикл отвечает за номер элемента в строке